# How to keep the same document layout in UITexView between different device sizes and orientations?

Tags: ios, uitextview, document, richtext

So let's say I have put some text and images in a `UITextView`, and it looks a certain way on iPhone 6 in portrait orientation. What I would like to achieve is to have that same look of the content (like a document, without misplaced text) of the `UITextView`, when I rotate the device, or when I open the same content on another device. What I'm thinking of as a solution is to pick a default width for the content and to have that width scaled among the different screen sizes/orientations. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want font size to scale as well or are you working with an HTML type document with specific formatting? Is there a specific reason for using `UITextView` instead of something more apt to displaying specific document formats?

Comment: The thing is, I would like it to behave like an html page, the way it scales when it has fixed width for example. The reason I'm using UITextView is because it allows for text wrap around draggable images with exclusionPaths.

Comment: If you're also scaling the images, then you might be able to get away with just scaling the font size. I can think of more complicated methods, but I would recommend starting with scaling the font size. You could even make a category on UIFont which looks at the screen orientation.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, thanks!